# What to name a mock injector/expectation setup interface for end to end tests?

Tags: testing, mocking, naming, inject

I am writing an interface into our system that will allow end to end tests to change the behaviour of the server in order to run through various automated test scenarios.
This interface will only be enabled in test-mode.

Things like;
Given the booking service is down
When I try book a trade
Then I see the booking failure message

I have done this sort of thing on previous projects but have never seen a 'nice' (concise, descriptive) name for the server-side testing service you use to set up these scenarios.

The best names I have so far are *MockInjector, TestSetupInjector, ServerTwiddler*.
Is there a more standard name out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard terminology used is [Test Hook](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Hook.html)

Comment: Cheers.  Catchier name and more 'Standard' than my suggestions.